# How to use switch statement to compare prices in C++

Tags: c++

for my project I have to calculate the cost of a mobile device service. I ask a user what package they want package a, b, or c. Then I have to ouput the price of each package which I have done. Now I have to use a switch statement to compare the prices of the package and ouput if they would save on switching package deals and how much they would save. Im not sure how to do this? Here is my code so far.

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 int main()
{
char a = 9.95;
char  b = 19.95;
char  c = 39.95;
char packagetype;

int  x=1, messageunits, Atotalcost, Btotalcost, Ctotalcost;

do
{
cout << "Which package do you choose(enter a, b, c,)" << endl;
cin >> a || b || c;
x++;
}
while(x < 2);       
{
cout << "how many message units(enter 1 - 672)" << endl;
cin >> messageunits;
x++;
}
while(x < 2);

Atotalcost = 995; // cost of package a, in cents
if(messageunits > 5){
Atotalcost += 100 * (messageunits - 5);
}

cout << "Your total cost is " << Atotalcost/100 << "." << Atotalcost%100 

Btotalcost = 1995;
if(messageunits > 15){
    Btotalcost += 50 * (messageunits - 15);


cout << "Your total cost is " << Btotalcost/100 << "." << Btotalcost%100 

Ctotalcost = 3995;
cout << "Your total cost is " << Ctotalcost/100 << "." << Ctotalcost%100 
 }
```

Comment: `switch()` over what actually? [Elaborate please](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30854491/edit). `switch` and `double` values certainly won't go well.

Comment: I have to compute the cost of packages A, B, and C which i did. Then, use a switch on the package value, print out the cost of the package, and compare to see if either of the other two are cheaper.

Comment: Why would you want to use a switch/case on doubles? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sure you're pressed to use a `switch() { case xy: ... }` to to so? An `if(<range_expression>) {} else if(<range_expression>) {}` cascade sounds to be more appropriate for me. Could you please state the actual requirement in your question.

Comment: I have to use a switch because thats what my instructor asked for on the project.

Comment: @decleater Could you please state the actual requirement in your question. You're missing a `do` after your 1st `do {} while();` loop BTW.

Comment: do you mean from the assignment directions?

Comment: @decleater I said _hard requirements/constraints_ from those _directions._

Comment: I have to compare the packages like this : If the choice is package A:

          print the cost

          compare with the prices of B and C

          report if the price of B or C is better

Comment: @decleater _"I have to compare ..."_ How does this introduce `switch()` anyway please?? Also clarify by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30854491/edit) please, as I've been requesting in my 1st comment already.

Comment: The `switch` statement is the wrong programming structure to use.  You need to compare using less than or greater than and a `switch` doesn't support that operation.

Comment: This is directly coming from the instructions. " So, as soon as you have a legal package and a legal number of message units, compute the cost of packages A, B, and C! Then, use a switch on the package value, print out the cost of the package, and compare to see if either of the other two are cheaper."

Comment: @decleater What's considered the _package value_ actually? I can't see any relating variable in your code. Also code like `char a = 9.95;` absolutely makes no sense at all. You'll get `9` as result, which isn't even a printable `char`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `switch` to differentiate between the packages.

First you need to correct this:

```
do
{
cout << "Which package do you choose(enter a, b, c,)" << endl;
cin >> a || b || c;
x++;
}
while(x < 2);
```

The `cin` statement doesn't do what you think it should.

Try something like this:

```
char package = 'z';
do
{
  cout << "Enter package: a, b, or c:";
  cin >> package;
  package = tolower(package);
} while ((package != 'a') && (package != 'b') && (package != 'c'));
```

Another implementation:

```
char package = 'Y';
while (true)
{
  cout << "Enter package: a, b, or c:";
  cin >> package;
  package = tolower(package);
  switch(package)
  {
    case 'a':
    case 'b':
    case 'c':
      break;
    default:
      cout << "Wrong entry, try again.\n\n";
      break;
  }
} // End: while(true)
```

You can do the comparisons by using a `switch` statement:

```
switch (package)
{
  case 'a':
    // Compare to B & C to find best fit.
    break;
  case 'b':
    // Compare to A & C to find best fit.
    break;
  case 'c':
    // Compare to A & B to find best fit.
    break;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I ran it, I ran it for package a and it printed out the cost of all three packages instead of just package a?

Comment: Please step aside from your screen so I can see your code.  Oh, never mind, my telescope lenses are cracked.  You'll have to post your changed code into your question or make a new question.

Comment: Its the same code except I change my first do while to yours char package = 'z';
do
{
  cout << "Enter package: a, b, or c:";
  cin >> package;
  package = tolower(package);
} while ((package != 'a') && (package != 'b') && (package != 'c')); When i run it, it keeps outputting the prices of all three packages instead of the one i ask for.